Get length in meters of a LineString using GeoTools
In another toolset I have used PostgreSQL to get the distance in meters text:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION length_text(geometry geometry) RETURNS text AS
$$
SELECT CASE
        WHEN ST_IsValid(geometry) 
            THEN TRUNC(ST_Length(geometry))::text
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
                STRICT
                PARALLEL SAFE;

Now I am using Java with GeoTools and need to do something similar. From the GeoTools documentation it is not clear how to do this.
What is the best way to get the length of linestring geometry using GeoTools?

Use the length method

GeoTools uses the JTS library for its geometries so you can use the getLength() method to get the length of your geometry - but be sure that you have understood this answer, and if you are dealing with latitude and longitude points then see this answer to work out how to get an answer in metres. Unless that is your line is pretty long in which case you should follow this answer.
